# I can I pull a specific data from multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to pull out the data from multidimensional array, but I get this   error each time I'm trying to write the correct path. I don't know what's the problem since the path is correct.

The error:

```
   Notice: Undefined index: shipper in C:\xampp\htdocs\xml\dood.php on line 31

    Notice: Undefined index: shipper in C:\xampp\htdocs\xml\dood.php on line 31
```

This is the array

```
Array
(
    [Shp] => Array
        (
            [test] => Array
                (
                    [shipper] => Array
                        (
                            [customer] => Array
                                (
                                    [address] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ad1] => new road
                                            [ad2] => newyork
                                            [company] => none
                                            [city] => JO
                                        )

                                    [newlang] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [reciver] => Array
                        (
                            [customer] => Array
                                (
                                    [address] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ad1] => new road
                                            [ad2] => newyork
                                            [company] => none
                                            [city] => JO
                                        )

                                    [newlang] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [test] => Array
                        (
                            [shipper] => Array
                                (
                                    [customer] => Array
                                        (
                                            [address] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [ad1] => new road
                                                    [ad2] => newyork
                                                    [company] => none
                                                    [city] => JO
                                                )

                                            [newlang] => 
                                        )

                                )

                            [reciver] => Array
                                (
                                    [customer] => Array
                                        (
                                            [address] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [ad1] => new road
                                                    [ad2] => newyork
                                                    [AddrLn3] => newyork
                                                    [company] => none
                                                    [city] => JO
                                                )

                                            [newlang] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

php code

```
$arr = $array; //Set this to your converted xml
$comps = $arr['Shp']['test'];

foreach($comps as $comp){
     echo $comp['shipper']['customer']['address']['ad1'];
}
```

How do I fix this error ?

Please help I tried everything possible

Comment: This's xml converted to  array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra key in the code. Remove it

```
$arr = $array; //Set this to your converted xml
$comps = $arr['Shp']['test'];

foreach($comps as $comp){
     echo $comp['customer']['address']['ad1'];
}
```

And if you want to add actions specific to shipper

```
foreach($comps as $key => $comp){ 
    if ($key == 'shipper') { 
        echo $comp['customer']['address']['ad1']; 
    } 
}
```

In your array there is two set of shipper and reciver. One is outer and another is inner. See below

```
Array
(
    [Shp] => Array
        (
            [test] => Array
                (
                    #####Top shipper array
                    [shipper] => Array
                        (
                            [customer] => Array
                                (
                                    [address] => Array(.....)
                                    [newlang] => 
                                )
                        )
                    #####Top reciver array
                    [reciver] => Array
                        (
                            [customer] => Array
                                (
                                    [address] => Array(.....)
                                    [newlang] => 
                                )
                        )
                    #####Sub array - test
                    [test] => Array
                        (
                        #####Sub shipper array
                            [shipper] => Array
                                (
                                    [customer] => Array
                                        (
                                            [address] => Array(.....)
                                            [newlang] => 
                                        )
                                )
                        #####Sub reciver array
                            [reciver] => Array
                                (
                                    [customer] => Array
                                        (
                                            [address] => Array(.....)
                                            [newlang] => 
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

If you want to iterate through inner array you can use above code.

If u wanna iterate through inner array use code below

```
$arr = $array; //Set this to your converted xml
$comps = $arr['Shp']['test']['test];
foreach($comps as $key => $comp){ 
    if ($key == 'shipper') { 
        echo $comp['customer']['address']['ad1']; 
    } 
}
```

Or if you wanna iterate through all and print only data when available

```
$arr = $array; //Set this to your converted xml
$comps = $arr['Shp']['test']['test];
foreach($comps as $key => $comp){ 
    if (isset($comp['shipper'])) { 
        echo $comp['shipper']['customer']['address']['ad1'];
    } 
}
```

Comment: so I can't select shipper,  because I have a  receiver as well to differentiate between the values, since they have the same key name

Comment: See! Updated answer

Comment: it works great, but for one path I mean it doesn't loop in all arrays, because  there should be 2  ad1 values not only one

Comment: See Updated answer !

Comment: Thank was great effort from you I really appreciate that. it works now flawlessly. Thanks man ^^.     one question. how long have you been a programmer

Comment: 6+ years :). No worries you will learn by time. After many years, you will find these things as silly. but you need to be a fresher before you can be an expert

Answer (score 2):

To fix the error, determine what is in your $comp variable/array.  The error occurs because what you are asking for is not there.

1. Comment out your line 31
2. Then echo the var_dump command. This will show you what is actually in your array.  This will display your array content in a readable format.

   foreach($comps as $comp){
      //echo $comp['shipper']['customer']['address']['ad1'];
      echo var_dump($comp);
   }

Look up the var_dump command in the [php reference manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

3. Once you can see what the content of the array is, you should have no trouble determining how to access the content.

Comment: I see that the first two keys doesn't appear in the path, is there something else please tell me

Comment: It's hard for me to tell because I do not see your results.  If you do not see the first two keys, then your not referencing what you think you are.

Comment: Try a var_dump on your main array.

Comment: From your code you expect everything to be in $arr = $array;  So do a var_dump on $arr and see what you get.

Comment: Please check my answer if you found it helpful in solving your issue